# Looping through table and sending <td> value in a URL

Tags: javascript, html-table

I have a table with a button in the first column, I want for the user to be able press that button and for the value in the second column to be sent as part of a URL. The table is created using a loop in `RPG`. However I am not sure how to go about this. I have tried just selecting it as an `ID` and making the whole thing a button by that just means I always get the value of the second column on the first row. Here is the HTML and Javascript:

```
<tr class="RowToClick">
  <td width="6%">
    <input name="button" type="button" style="width:100%" onClick="sendProdCod()" value="+">
   </td>                        
  <td width="12%" id="prodCod"><%= ProdCod%>
    <div align="right"></div>
  </td>
  <td width="15%" align="right"><%= %CHAR(SchedWeight)%>
    <div align="right"></div>
  </td>
  <td width="15%" align="right"><%= %CHAR(TotSchedWeight)%></td>
  <td width="13%" align="right"><%= %CHAR(Stkonha)%></td>
  <td width="13%" align="right"><%= %CHAR(STKAWINS)%></td>
  <td width="12%" align="right"><%= %CHAR(SchedProd)%></td>
  <td width="14%" align="right" bgcolor="#CCD5E3"><%= %CHAR(PROJSTK)%></td>               
</tr>

function sendProdCod(){
  var productCode = document.getElementById('ProdCod').value;
  url = 'http://brmappsvr:7018/Enquiries/CMENCH.rpgle?ProductCode=' + productCode;
  window.location.href = url;
}
```

Comment: How many row in your table ? Id must be unique.

Comment: There could be any number of rows, depending on the RPG loop

Comment: It s a problem, id must be unique otherwise js can make error, why you dont do : `onClick="sendProdCod('<%= ProdCod%>')"` ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to change `.value` to `.textContent` in

```
var productCode = document.getElementById('ProdCod').value;
```

`value` is an attribute used for inputs, while `textContent` is used to retrieve the text from node. Since `prodCod` is a `td`-element.

To make it safer (not depending on the id), you could do this:

```
function sendProdCod(){
 var prodCodElement = this.parentElement.nextElementSibling;
 var productCode = prodCodElement.textContent;

url = 'http://brmappsvr:7018/Enquiries/CMENCH.rpgle?ProductCode=' + productCode;
window.location.href = url;
```

}

You need to give the `onclick` the `this` keyword: onClick="sendProdCod(this)" for this to work.

Comment: True about `.value` and `.textContent` but id must be unique, in table with multiple row it can generate error only first or last id will always be return.

Answer (score 1):

Like i post in comment :

```
    <tr class="RowToClick">
                    <td width="6%">

                    <input name="button" type="button" style="width:100%" onClick="sendProdCod('<%= ProdCod%>')" value="+"></td>

                    <td width="12%"><%= ProdCod%>
                    <div align="right"></div></td>
                    <td width="15%" align="right"><%= %CHAR(SchedWeight)%>
                  <div align="right"></div></td>
                    <td width="15%" align="right"><%= %CHAR(TotSchedWeight)%></td>
                    <td width="13%" align="right"><%= %CHAR(Stkonha)%></td>
                    <td width="13%" align="right"><%= %CHAR(STKAWINS)%></td>
                    <td width="12%" align="right"><%= %CHAR(SchedProd)%></td>
                    <td width="14%" align="right" bgcolor="#CCD5E3"><%= %CHAR(PROJSTK)%></td>               
                </tr>





 function sendProdCod(productCode){

    url = 'http://brmappsvr:7018/Enquiries/CMENCH.rpgle?ProductCode=' + productCode;
    window.location.href = url;
}
```